# Is $SU(n)/\mathbb Z_n$ a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I know that $\mathbb Z_n$ is the center of the Lie group $SU(n)$. Therefore, the quotient $SU(n)/\mathbb Z_n$ forms a group. However, I am not sure whether it also forms a Lie group. I also wonder what is $\mathfrak{su}(n)/\mathbb Z_n$ at the Lie algebra level.

So far, I have only seen examples of quotient group $G/H$ in which the quotient $H$ is itself a connected Lie group; then if $H$ is a normal, closed, connected Lie subgroup, $G/H$ is a Lie group. However, I don't have intuition for what we would obtain if we quotient a Lie group by a finite group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if $G$ is a Lie group and $N$ is a normal subgroup which is closed (in the topological sense), then $G/N$ is a Lie group. If $N$ is discrete, then the projection map $\pi : G \to G/N$ is a covering map. In particular, there is an isomorphism $(d\pi)_e : T_eG \to T_e(G/N)$, so the Lie algebras of $G$ and $G/N$ are isomorphic.

Therefore $SU(n)/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a Lie group and its Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Comment: Just to know: Is it obvious that $\mathsf{SU}(n)/\Bbb Z_n$ is not simply connected? I think using Lie' third theorem it is not simply connected.

Comment: @C.F.G: You don't need Lie's theorem. If $X$ is a simply connected topological space and $G$ is a discrete group which acts freely on $X$, then $X \to X/G$ is a covering map with deck transformation group $G$, so $\pi_1(X/G) \cong G$. In particular, $\pi_1(SU(n)/\mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ so $SU(n)/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not simply connected for $n > 1$.